# Gson: serialização de datas em vários formatos

Tags: java, gson

Estou usando Gson e preciso serializar uma classe com diferentes formatos de datas:

```
@TimeStampField(onlyDate = false)
private Timestamp datahora

@TimeStampField(onlyDate = true)
private Timestamp diaLimite
```

Eu queria pegar essas anotations dentro do meu JsonSerializer e definir o formato da minha data (`yyyy/MM/dd` ou `yyyy/MM/dd'T'12:30:00.0'Z'`)

É possível? Há alguma alternativa?

Comment: É possível e existem diversas alternativas ;P Como você está fazendo até então, algum problema específico?

Comment: Sim, é possível, você pode registrar um `type adapter` para os tipos de tempo que você quer tratar, neste post é mostrado um exemplo completo de como fazê-lo no Gson. http://www.gitshah.com/2011/04/how-to-work-with-json-on-android-part-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um TypeAdapter para o Timestamp, o problema é que eu trabalho com Timestamp para todos os campos de datas, mas o Webserservice é restritivo aos formatos ("yyyy/MM/dd" ou "yyyy/MM/dd'T'12:30:00.0'Z'"), a melhor forma de burlar isso foi criar uma classe que estende Timestamp "Datestamp" e criar um *adapter* pra ela.
Daí os campos que eu serializo somente com data são do tipo Datestamp

Comment: Seria interessante você publicar a classe que você utilizou para resolver o problema, para que outras pessoas possam se beneficiar da solução.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de começar, sugiro que use o formato correto **ISO8601**, que é `2018-07-11T23:15:15.600Z`.

Para fazer o procedimento que voce quer voce terá que implementar `com.google.gson.TypeAdapter<Timestamp>`

Exemplo:

```
public static class MyDateTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter< Timestamp > {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dataEhora = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS" );
    private final SimpleDateFormat data = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" );

    @Override
    public void write( JsonWriter out, Timestamp value ) throws IOException {
        if ( value == null ) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            if ( value.getNanos() == 0 && value.getSeconds() == 0 && value.getMinutes() == 0 && value.getHours() == 0 ) {
                out.value( this.data.format( value ) );
            } else {
                out.value( this.dataEhora.format( value ) );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Timestamp read( JsonReader in ) throws IOException {
        if ( in != null ) {
            String dataString = in.nextString();
            final SimpleDateFormat format;
            if ( dataString.length() == 10 ) {
                format = this.data;
            } else {
                format = this.dataEhora;
            }
            Date parsedDate;
            try {
                parsedDate = format.parse( dataString );
                return new Timestamp( parsedDate.getTime() );
            } catch ( ParseException e ) {
                return null;
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora você deve criar a instância do seu `Gson` setando o adapter criado, veja abaixo:

```
class Exemplo {
    Timestamp dataComHora;
    Timestamp data;
}

class Teste {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter( Timestamp.class, new MyDateTypeAdapter() ).create();
        String json = "{\"dataComHora\":\"2018/07/11T11:30:13.795\",\"data\":\"2018/08/11\"}";

        System.out.println( "entrada: " + json );
        Exemplo exemplo = gson.fromJson( json, Exemplo.class );
        System.out.println( "saida: " + gson.toJson( exemplo ) );
    }
}
```